# Quicksort Infinite Loop Issue in C++

Tags: c++, infinite-loop, quicksort

I have extensively tested the swap and partition function for the following code and they appear to be correct; however, when I try to execute quicksort it goes into an infinite loop. I'm assuming the issue happens from my returned value in partition, but I am not entirely sure what it is.

```
void swap_G(int *begin, int *end)
{
    int temp = *begin;
    *begin = *end;
    *end = temp;
    return;
}

int* partition(int* begin, int* end)
{
   if (begin >= end) {
      return begin;
   }

   int pivot = *end;
   int* temp_Begin = begin, *temp_End = end;
   temp_End--;

   while (temp_Begin < temp_End)
   {
      while (*temp_Begin < pivot && temp_Begin < temp_End)
      {
         temp_Begin++;
      }
      while (*temp_End > pivot && temp_End > temp_Begin)
      {
         temp_End--;
      }
      swap_G(temp_Begin, temp_End);
   }
   swap_G(end, temp_Begin);
   return temp_Begin;
}

void quicksort_G(int* begin, int* end)
{
   if (begin >= end)
   {
      return;
   }
   int* mid = partition(begin, end);
   quicksort_G(begin, --mid);
   quicksort_G(mid + 1, end);
}
```

Comment: Let initially `begin + 1 == end`, what value will `partition()` return? What values will then get recursive calls to `quicksort_G`?

Answer (score 0):

Any reason for using all those pointers? A problem I see is with mid

```
int* mid = partition(begin, end);
quicksort_G(begin, --mid)
```

This is decrementing the *pointer* to mid. For example:

```
int* temp = new int( 6 );
std::cout << *temp << std::endl;
std::cout << *(--temp) << std::endl;
```

You'll get

```
6
-33686019
```

Printing the memory address would yield

```
std::cout << temp << std::endl;
std::cout << (--temp) << std::endl;

00BE48B0
00BE48AC//Decremented by sizeof(int). Garbage data
```

I would see if I could get rid of the pointers altogether. You're passing that mid which will be used as end in the next step. But in partition, end will be swapped. So when you return from the first recursive step mid is already messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is possibly in your `partition` function, **and** certainly in the way you use its result. The partition function should reorder array items such that the pivot value falls into its final position. Then recursive calls handle items *before* the pivot and *after* it, but the pivot itself does not get into processing in the deeper recursion levels. That guarantees the amount of data decreases with each recursion level, so the recursion must stop at some level.